# Extract exact boundary of DEM from another raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a DEM and I want to extract this DEM by using another raster. Basically I need only those DEM pixels that are covered by second raster. When I try to clip, the output gives the whole extent of the second raster. Extract by mask is also not working.

Comment: Set extent to intersection of inputs and do Con(~IsNull(other), DEM) in raster calculator.

Comment: @FelixIP Still its not working

Comment: Reclassify 'other raster' so that areas you want to keep = 1 and areas you do not want to keep = NoData.  Multiply the  resulting raster with your original DEM.

Comment: @CBG Thank you. Problem Solved